# GNOME settings without GUI

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gnome, raspberry-pi, vnc

I am trying to run a VNC server on a Raspberry Pi which I don't have physical access to.
I've installed `realvnc-vnc-server` and enabled VNC in `raspi-config`

I'm running into an issue with encryption on the VNC service - trying to connect from OSX using the built in Screen Sharing application.
I've seen this issue before on Ubuntu, and normally follow the steps in this answer to resolve it; http://askubuntu.com/questions/463486/can-no-longer-use-screen-share-to-connect-mac-to-ubuntu-since-upgrading-to-14-04

However as I have no GUI to open `dconf-editor` I'm not sure where to change the `require-encryption` setting. I have read about `gsettings` but I can't figure out which package(s) to install to use it.

Comment: Just use "package search": https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gsettings&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=amd64 (use http://packages.ubuntu.com if you're using Ubuntu and not Raspbian — from your tags, it's hard to figure out what you're talking about). I mean "search contents of packages".

Comment: The link you've posted applies to ubuntu's built in remote desktop sharing app only, it has nothing to do with RealVNC's server that comes with Raspbian. What error do you get when you try to connect to the server?